How can HTML "time" / "datetime-local" input be useful if timezone is not known on the server?
I'm confused about the reasoning behind <input type="time" /> and <input type="datetime-local">.
As the name suggests, datetime-local expects the time to be in the user's timezone. But how can I actually know the timezone when rendering the date on the client?
The same goes for processing the input when such a field is posted to the server: I cannot think of anything useful one can do with the value of such a field, when the timezone is not known.
I'm aware that I can query the user's timezone with JavaScript, but I cannot believe that these fields depend on JavaScript to be useful.
Am I missing something?

Mostly explained here:  Date/time inputs are convenient for the developer; they provide an easy UI for choosing dates and times, and they normalize the data format sent to the server, regardless of the user's locale

Thanks, but can you explain how the time information sent to the server can be used, assuming the web page is accessed by international users?

To make this more clear: Let's assume we're building a calendar application. The user creates an event setting a date and time. Now, when the form is submitted, a warning should be displayed if an overlapping event already exists. How can this be done when there's no timezone information included?

Maybe this particular section answers your question: setting_timezones -- make sure you scroll down to the "Setting timezones" section.

@PeterJames: The article suggests I should add a  element to the form and let the user pick their timezone. Besides this sounding quite inconvenient to me, I wonder how this would work, when a user is editing an existing item. The form would show with all datetime-local fields populated in UTC. Now, when the user picks their timezone, the current value would still show in UTC. So it really seems that there is no practical way of having time user input without relying on JavaScript. Crazy.

The examples on that page don't populate the datetime-local fields, and one of the examples seems to be able to pick up my local time correctly. Maybe it's inconvenient, but I guess that's what happens when the specs change.
